# How to speed up truncating text to specific word count in nim?

Tags: performance, strings, nim

I have a web application, as part of it I regularly have to send out "overviews" of records in a database, which contain shortened excerpts of a description-text of that record.

What the code is supposed to do:

1. Take an HTML string
2. Remove the HTML brackets so that only text remains
3. cut it down to `SHORT_DESCRIPTION_WORD_COUNT` words
4. if there are more than `SHORT_DESCRIPTION_WORD_COUNT` words, add "..." at the end

My current implementation looks like this:

```
import std/[strutils, strformat, htmlparser, xmltree, enumerate]

const SHORT_DESCRIPTION_WORD_COUNT: int = 40

proc truncate*(text: string): string =
  let cleanedString = text.parseHtml().innerText
  let splitString = cleanedString.split(" ")
  
  if splitString.len() <= SHORT_DESCRIPTION_WORD_COUNT:
    result = cleanedString
  else:
    result.add(splitString[0..SHORT_DESCRIPTION_WORD_COUNT-1].join(" "))
    result.add("...")
```

Looking at some valgrind data, I determined that this proc takes up a sizeable chunk of time and would benefit from being speed-performance optimized a bit.

I'm mostly wondering how to do that though. I believe the intensive steps here are the cleaning up of the HTML and then splitting the string, I'm not sure how to avoid those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with Yardanico in nim's discord for a bit, there is 1 significant improvement that can be made here and a couple minor ones:

#### Main Improvement: Use the split iterator

I use the split **proc** and assign the seq of strings into a variable to iterate over.
That is wasteful, when you can use the split **iterator** instead.

Since you still need to track which word you're at to know when you hit `SHORT_DESCRIPTION_WORD_COUNT`, you can use `std/enumerate`, which is sugar over writing `var i=0` and manually incrementing that within the loop.

```
proc truncate_breakfor_enumerate*(text: string): string =
    let cleanedString = text.parseHtml().innerText

    for i, str in enumerate(cleanedString.split(" ")):
        result.add(" " & str)
        if i >= SHORT_DESCRIPTION_WORD_COUNT:
            result.add("...")
            break
```

##### Minor Improvement: Pre-allocate the string

This matters mostly for scenarios in which you add longer strings. Having the string pre-allocated to roughly the correct size can reduce the number of memory allocations needed overall. That is, because if the string outgrows its size as you add substrings to it, it will need to be copied elsewhere. You can do this with `newStringOfCap`.

This will only even start to matter if you start having a fairly sizeable amount of text (>5000 chars) and even then the improvements are somewhat marginal.

```
proc truncate_breakformemoryalloc*(text: string): string =
    let cleanedString = text.parseHtml().innerText
    result = newStringOfCap(400) # <-- The important bit

    for i, str in enumerate(cleanedString.split(" ")):
        result.add(" " & str)
        if i >= SHORT_DESCRIPTION_WORD_COUNT:
            result.add("...")
            break
```

Running these over a benchmark with one of normal text and another more artificial one with regularly words above 50 characters, these are my results:

```
name ......................................... min time      avg time    std dv   runs
truncate classic ............................. 0.046 ms      0.053 ms    ±0.004  x1000
truncate_breakfor_enumerate................... 0.021 ms      0.023 ms    ±0.001  x1000
truncate_breakfor_enumerate_memoryalloc ...... 0.021 ms      0.025 ms    ±0.004  x1000
truncate classic long ........................ 0.050 ms      0.082 ms    ±0.019  x1000
truncate_breakfor_enumerate long ............. 0.036 ms      0.040 ms    ±0.007  x1000
truncate_breakfor_enumerate_memoryalloc long ..0.035 ms      0.038 ms    ±0.004  x1000
```

Both of these versions should do perfectly fine for any purposes.